# Laravel fetching eloquent relationship throws static method error

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent, relationships

Hi I'm using Laravel 4 and I have three models, `Project` (table name `projects`), `Status` (tables name: `statuses`) and `AssignedProjectBoardStatus` (table name: `assigned_project_board_statuses`). Now when I create a project statuses are automatically assigned if they are not selected from a list. The `assigned_project_board_statuses` table has two foreign keys the table schema is below:

`id|project_id|status_id|order|created_at|updated_at`

`project_id` and `status_id` are the foreign keys. Now I have a model as so:

`app/models/AssignedProjectBoardStatus.php`

```
class AssignedProjectBoardStatus extends AbstractModel {

public function projects() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Project');
}
public function statuses() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Status');
}
}
```

`app/models/Project.php`

```
class Project extends AbstractModel
{
 public function assignedProjectBoardStatus() {
    return $this->hasMany('AssignedProjectBoardStatus');
 }
```

`app/models/Status.php`

```
class Status extends AbstractModel {
public function assignedProjectBoardStatus() {
        return $this->hasMany('AssignedProjectBoardStatus');
    }
```

There when I am fetching the projects and I want to see the statuses assigned I would call this as follows:

`Project::assignedScrumBoardStatuses();`

However this throws the following error:

`Non-static method Project::assignedProjectBoardStatuses() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

So I've changed the function as follows:

`app/models/Project.php`

```
class Project extends AbstractModel
{
 public **static** function assignedProjectBoardStatus() {
    return $this->hasMany('AssignedProjectBoardStatus');
 }
```

However this then threw the following error:

`Using $this when not in object context`

So i then changed the function as follows:

```
 public **static** function assignedScrumBoardStatuses() {
        return **static::**hasMany('AssignedScrumBoardStatus');
    }
```

And this then threw this error:

`Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::hasMany() should not be called statically`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how I can get the assigned statuses from the model??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t call `Project::assignedScrumBoardStatuses()` because when you do, the `Project` model doesn’t know which record you’re trying to fetch the assigned scrum board status for. It has no context.

Instead, find a record so you have a model instance, and you can then call your relation methods on that:

```
$project = Project::find($id)->assignedScrumBoardStatuses();
```

Comment: ahh I see, I get this error now though: `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany could not be converted to string`?

Comment: @001221 Can you update your question with what the `assignedScrumBoardStatuses()` looks like currently?

Comment: You probably try to output the assignedScrumBoardStatuses. Remove the parentheses `()` from assignedScrumBoardStatuses so Laravel automatically calls `->get()` on the hasMany relation. This yields a collection.